# How can I pass an object to a specific view on a another page in TYPO3?

Tags: redirect, view, typo3

I have a simple controller with two actions:

1. listAction - shows a list of my objects
2. showAction - shows the detail page of an object

I am using a flexform for my plugin to define the detail page and can access to this via settings array in my controller. The standard view (list view) shows all my objects with a link to the detail page. This link will be generated by this fluid link action:

```
<f:link.action action="show" arguments="{example: example}" pageUid="{pageId}">details</f:link.action>
```

The generated links looks as follows:

```
<a href="index.php?id=38&amp;tx_example_p1%5Bexample%5D=5&amp;tx_example_p1%5Baction%5D=show&amp;tx_example_p1%5Bcontroller%5D=Example&amp;cHash=89353bbb46f26f41969f02800c5ae530">details</a>
```

I think that's ok and the redirect to the correct detail page is also working, but it seems that the **show view** is not showing up, because it will not be rendered. My showAction and my Show.html looks as follows:

Show.html

```
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="main">
    <h1>Detail page</h1>
    <f:debug>{example}</f:debug>
</f:section>
```

showAction:

```
/**
 * Shows the details page
 *
 * @param \Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Example $example
 * @return void
 */
public function showAction(\Fox\Example\Domain\Model\Example $example) {

    $this->view->assign('example', $example);

}
```

So it seems that the action of the fluid link action viewhelper will be ignored. When I remove the **pageUid="{pageId}"** from the link action above I can see the show view, but then I will be not redirected to the correct detail page.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Ok it is working when I include the frontend Plug-In to the detail page, too. Is there a way to pass up the double include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ok it is working when I include the frontend Plug-In to the detail page, too. Is there a way to pass up the double include?

No, it is supposed to work like this - a plugin has to be present on a page if it should be rendered there. This presence can be indirect though:

- You could reference the plugin (using a record of type "Include Records", or some reference mechanism from an extension).
- You could include it using TypoScript (frequently used if it should
  be on many pages).

Anyway, if there is no specific reason to have separate pages in the page tree for detail and list view, just put them on one page using the same plugin.